# Firebase Audience not showing users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm integrating Firebase analytics in my Android App. I have successfully logged events and am able to see the number of users and the count of the event triggered. Now I have created and audience for an event

> add_to_cart_click_success

which has 21 users and 20 users were registered after the audience was created[image: Add_To_Cart_Click_Success Event]

[image: TestAddToCart Audience]

As can be see from the images the Audience still shows <10 users and hence won't show me data for that audience.

I don't understand why the number of users in the audience is not getting updated but the number of users in the Event is getting updated properly.

Also when creating a new Audience, I don't see my custom parameters when applying filter after selecting an event. Do we need to manually input the parameter name and then apply the filter or am I doing something wrong here?

Also same thing is happening for my other audience as well. The event shows 27 users but the audience still shows <10 users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you create an Audience it starts clean and accumulates data from that point onward. Click on question mark in Firebase Console - Audiences tab for more info. So just wait a day and your audience should get new data (if there will be any).

I tried setting custom parameters, but it seems that you have to manually input parameter name (in search field in dialog), press enter and then you can continue to set up your filter.

Comment: I created audience before release the APK for internal testing and the above users in the events is after the audience was created, I applied the date filter to show the users only after the audience was created.

Comment: Thanks, that's really dodgy. Thought all the past data were already in BigQuery or some other kind of storage. Even I don't mind waiting I would to see at least "processing" status update or some kind of estimation when data is ready

Answer (score 1):

The audience filters will show up when there are more than the threshold (10 users) that satisfy the filters. However, the "users" will need to have different AD IDs. Please see this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147957/firebase-dashboard-audiences-probable-bug) for more information.