# Firebase: Dashboard / Audiences probable bug?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console, audience

Ok I'm pretty new to firebase and analytics but I'm seeing some kind of incongruency between what the dashboard is showing me and what the Audiences tab shows me.
Dashboard:

[image]

and the Audiences (predefined Audience All Users):

[image]

Any ideas if I'm looking at this the wrong way or if it's just a bug? 
Thanks!!

Comment: What the mismatch that you're seeing?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, the dashboard shows 13 active users in the last month but the Audiences tab shows me less than 10 users for the **All Users** audience. I guess this is why if I filter the dashboard by **All Users** filter it shows me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The threshold of 10 is actually based on Advertising Identifiers (and not Analytics "users").  And so, if your set of 13 Monthly Active Users has fewer than 10 Advertising Identifiers among them (for example, if you just uninstalled/re-installed 13 times on one device), the report will still not meet the threshold requirements.

Comment: so if we use the same device, uninstalling the apk and reseting the Advertisement ID each time, it should pass the threshold activating the **All Users** audience, right?

Comment: Yes Dieguinho, it should, as long as your change the advertisement ID