# Firebase RemoteConfig and conditions with audience

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

In Firebase I am trying to set up some RemoteConfig parameters that should have different values based on the audience membership of the user that is logged in to an Android app we are developing.

The problem is that I am not allowed to set up a RemoteConfig condition based on audience. The option is greyed out.
Also, if I attempt to view events filtered by my Audience in Firebase
Analytics, no events appear.

My audience configuration in Firebase looks like this:
[image: Firebase audience configuration]

I understand that I my audience needs to be "reasonably well
developed" for them to be targetted by RemoteConfig
(https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)

So I have followed this procedure to populate the audience:

1. Install app
2. app triggers "login" event with custom user property "chain_id" set.
3. uninstall app
4. reset advertising ID (as noted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39183589/930653)

I have repeated this about 20 times and waited 48 hours.
The audience ("Minibuss") now lists 23 members:

[image]

But still, I can not use the audience as a condition in RemoteConfig,
or filter events in Firebase Analytics based on this audience.

I have tried looking at DebugView in the Firebase console, and I can see the user has the correct porperty "chain_id" set to 524, and so the event should match the audience.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This rule requires an App ID rule to select an app associated with
>   your Firebase project.

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters

You need to set Applies if "App" and choose your app, and then User audience option will be available.